# Django model default value in response

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to have a default value in my django model response value

Sample model query

```
myModel.objects.filter().values("username", "user_gender")
```

I want to have a default value in response

It must be like

```
Select username, user_gender, 'delhi' as country from mytable
```

Please let me know if any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional value to queryset using [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) expression:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

myModel.objects.filter().values("username", "user_gender", default_city=Value('delhi', output_field=CharField()))
```

You can find more details about `values()` method [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).